# Deeply Nested ActiveRecord Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model `Dataset` which belongs to an `Instruction`, which belongs to a `Run` which belongs to a `Project` which belongs to an `Organization`. I'm trying to retrieve all the Dataset entries that belong to a particular organization.

How can I query that deeply? I feel as though I should be able to accomplish this with `where()` but I can't figure out how to achieve my desired result.

Comment: I would keep an extra `belongs_to :organization` in `Dataset` model to make it easier to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eager_load method:

```
data_set = Dataset.eager_load(instruction: {project: :organization}).where('organizations.id = ?', organization.id)
```

refer this blog for clarification https://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/